# `Fault` keyword in try block

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, try-catch

While exploring an assembly in reflector I stumbled upon a `fault` keyword in a compiler generated class.

Do any of you know the meaning if this keyword?

**C#**

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    bool flag;
    try
    {
        // [...]
    }
    fault
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

**vb.net**

```vb
Private Function MoveNext() As Boolean 
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Try 
        ' [...]
    Fault
        Me.Dispose
    End Try
    Return flag
End Function
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Do any of you know the meaning if this keyword?

Yes. It's not valid C#, but in IL it's the equivalent of `finally`, but only if an exception has been thrown.

There's no direct correlation in C#, which is why the decompiler can't decompile it to proper C#. You could *emulate* it with something like:

```
bool success = false;
try
{
    ... stuff ...
    success = true; // This has to occur on all "normal" ways of exiting the
                    // block, including return statements.
}
finally
{
    if (!success)
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

I mention it in my [iterator block implementation details](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) article which looks relevant to your particular example :)

Comment: So... did anything ever come of the `yield do` idea in that article? Also... `fault` sounds like it'd be a nice addition to C# :)

Comment: @Corey: Nope, I'm afraid not.